# Looping through array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I have an array just like this:

[image]

The question I have is how can I foreach through the objects. I want to associate each of those to a container.

So I tried this:

```
foreach ($data['plates'] as $index => $element) {
    //Don't worry about the container_id. 
    $plates = Plate::find($element['plate_id'])->plateContainer()->associate($data['container_id'])->save();
}
```

But can't seem to get this working. Any ideas what I am doing wrong or missing?

FYI—The relations between the models

**Plate Model**

```
public function plateContainer()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\PlateContainer');
}
```

**PlateContainer Model**

```
public function plates()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Plate');
}
```

**Update #1:** The array is coming from AngularJS after submitting a simple form. Sorry forgot to mention this.

**Update #2:** Ok. I gave the following a try.

```
foreach ($data['plates'] as $element)
{
    foreach ($element as $value)
    {
        $plates = Plate::find($value)->plateContainer()->associate($data['container_id'])->save();
    }
}
```

…but still not getting it to work. Checking the DB, it only shows the first plate was updated with the given container.

I tried `dd($value);` It only shows 1

Comment: Is it a js array or a php array?

Comment: Why is javascript tagged here?

Comment: @callback I am sorry. I forgot to mention. The array coming from AngularJS . I will update the post

Comment: @Pete Sorry! Just updated the post. No it's not a php array. Coming from AngularJS

Answer (score 1):

Your `$data['plates']` contains 2 associative arrays: [0] => {etc...} and [1] => {etc...}.
So you need a nested loop for that.

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($data['plates']); $i++) {
    foreach ($data['plates'][$i] as $index => $element) {
    //Don't worry about the container_id. 
    $plates = Plate::find($element['plate_id'])->plateContainer()->associate($data['container_id'])->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but what if I had more than 2 elements?

Comment: Updated my answer. Instead of hard coding the loop limit, use count() function instead to count the number of elements of the array.

Comment: I tried this again. It's weird, it only updates a single plate with a given container. I updated my post once again.

Comment: Why find($value)? Why not find($value['plate_id'])?

Answer (score 0):

Something was off.

```
   foreach ($data['plates'] as $index => $element) {


  $plates = Plate::find($element['plate_id'])->plateContainer()->associate($data['container_id'])->save();
}
```

Did the trick